Ethernet design review
So I have designed my first ethernet layout inspired by this project and I would be really grateful if I could get some feedback whether the layout is good and will work fine, or if I should make some adjustments.
As you can see, I have added 0 ohm resistor and also a 2kV - 1nF capacitor to the layout to connect the grounds so that can be misleading. I will only use one of these options but I wasn't sure which method is better, so I included both options in the design.
Here is the schematic:

and this is the pcb layout:



The activity LED might not work. However the Ethernet did not really differ from datasheet implementation. However, you should definitely ask about RS-485. This is why review questions are difficult. There is no correct answer, the part you ask is not really a huge issue, but another part you don't ask about requires an hour long discussion why it is done that way and why it won't work and what changes there should be.

@Justme is there something I have missed about the LEDs? I followed the diagrams on the page 14 and 15 of this document. But anyways, it's not that big of a deal if the ethernet is all right. Is the problem with the RS-485 that I haven't included a GND connection for the buses? If so, do I need it if I will be using the same power supply for all the connected nodes on the bus?

If you use the capacitor between grounds, will the activity LED work? Yes not having ground for RS-485 is one thing, if all devices share ground it is not an issue, but you have no ground for shield of the twisted pair if you happen to need it. Also you have copied some auto-transmit-enable circuit for RS-485 transmit, do you think it will work?

@Justme Im not sure, but if not I can use the 0ohm resistor method. In which case do I need to connect the shield? Well I hope so, is there a reason it might not work? :D
